# How to return only value for find option in mongo database C#

Tags: c#, mongodb

I try to retrieve the following data using find the query from mongo query.

```
Data
  {
    "_id":objectid(123123),
    "Reading":89,
    "Time":1323,
"Company":"test"  }

ProjectionDefinition<BsonDocument> project = Builders<BsonDocument>.Projection.Include("Reading").Include("TIme").Exclude("_id");
FilterDefinition<BsonDocument> filterDefintion = Builders<BsonDocument>.Filter.Eq("Company","test");
collection.Find(filterDefintion).Project(project).ToList();
```

Result expectation:

```
  [
    89,
    1323
  ]
```

Actual result is

> { "Reading":89,  "Time":1323 }

Is it possible or not?

Comment: You say you "try to retrieve" and you have "expectation", but you don't tell us what actually happened. Does your `Find` work? What does that return ? (your `Data` does not seem to have anything to do with your `Find`, hence the question).

Comment: no.its not working.
i got the output as key value pair.
[{
    "Reading":89,
    "Time":1323
    }]

Comment: @crashmstr.sorry for editing.i miss the company name in data

Comment: `{ 89, 1323 }` is not BSON or JSON, and it does look like you are getting only the values you want, so while you could build a string that matches your expectation, your expectation is non-standard.

Comment: @crashmstr     is there any way to change the data using mongo query

Comment: The only way you could do that would be to format that string yourself with the results you are getting. Since you don't explain why you want the data like this or how you plan on using it, I can only repeat that your expected format is not JSON or BSON and would be a non-standard representation of the data.

Comment: Your expected result is not valid, so obviously it doesn't return it. Are you sure you don't mean `[89,123]`, i.e an array of values?

Comment: @crashmstr
actually, i want to plot the time series graph in react web app.Data is too large .so I can't format it in the web application.

Comment: @Liam is it n array or object not a matter .
return value is an array is not a problem for me.i want to remove the key from return data.

Comment: @Liam
is it possible to return as array?

Comment: Right you've now just totally moved the goalposts with that edit...If your going to do that I'm prob not helping anymore. I have better things to do than to talk you though this simple task while you keep changing what you want.